# Combining Like Terms/ LinkedList Polynomial [Java]

Tags: java, polynomials

So my issue here is getting this program to combine like terms, I've tried about 3 different ways of going about this and cannot figure it out. I can sort the array in somewhat the correct order but not get it to combine.

```
    public static Node multiply(Node poly1, Node poly2) {
    Node polynomial1 = poly1;
    Node polynomial2 = poly2;
    Node mult = poly2;
    Node temp3 = null;
    float cmb = 0;
    int cmbExp = 0; 

    // the sum of the polynomials
    Node temp = null;
    float coeffProd;
    int expSum;

    if(poly1 == null)
        return "Enter a Different Polynomial";

    if(poly2 == null)
        return "Enter a Different Polynomial";


    // while loop if either polynomial runs out of terms. This avoids nullpointerexception
    while (polynomial1 != null) {
        while(polynomial2 != null){

            coeffProd = polynomial1.term.coeff * polynomial2.term.coeff;
            expSum = polynomial1.term.degree + polynomial2.term.degree;
            temp = new Node(coeffProd, expSum, temp);

            polynomial2 = polynomial2.next;
        }
        polynomial1 = polynomial1.next;
        polynomial2 = mult; 

     }
    // my attempt at combining
    Node temp2 = temp.next;
    while(temp != null){
        while(temp2 != null){
            if(temp.term.degree == temp2.term.degree){
                cmb = temp.term.coeff + temp2.term.coeff;
                cmbExp = temp.term.degree;
           }
            temp2 = temp2.next;
            temp3 = new Node(cmb,cmbExp,temp3);
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
// Reverses the Polynomial into the correct sequence
    Node flip = temp;
    Node ans = null;
    while (flip != null)
    {
        if (flip.term.coeff == 0)
        {
            flip = flip.next;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            ans = new Node(flip.term.coeff, flip.term.degree, ans);
            flip = flip.next;
        }
    }

    if (ans == null)
        return null;
    else
    {
   return ans;
    }  
}
```

Result:
32.0x^9 + 16.0x^8 + -12.0x^6 + 36.0x^5 + -16.0x^7 + -8.0x^6 + 6.0x^4 + -18.0x^3 + 16.0x^5 + 8.0x^4 + -6.0x^2 + 18.0x + 24.0x^4 + 12.0x^3 + -9.0x + 27.0

I need to combine these like terms.

Comment: You should debug this program to find what exact operation is not working like you expect so you can ask a specific question about just that one small mechanism.

Comment: The current method to combine like terms returns me a 0

Answer (score 0):

The combining can be simplified if you iterate through the degrees.  This also guarantees that the combined polynomial is created with the degrees in sequential order.

The following working code demonstrates one possible way to combine, and create the desired result.

```
public Node multiply(Node poly1, Node poly2) {

    if (poly1 == null || poly2 == null)
        return null;

    Node polynomial1 = poly1;
    Node polynomial2 = poly2;

    Node allTerms = null;
    float coeffProd;
    int expSum;

    int maxDegree = 0;
    while (polynomial1 != null) {
        while (polynomial2 != null) {
            coeffProd = polynomial1.term.coeff * polynomial2.term.coeff;
            expSum = polynomial1.term.degree + polynomial2.term.degree;
            allTerms = new Node(coeffProd, expSum, allTerms);
            if (expSum > maxDegree)
                maxDegree = expSum;
            polynomial2 = polynomial2.next;
        }
        polynomial1 = polynomial1.next;
        polynomial2 = poly2;
    }

    /*  Combine terms  */
    Node combinedNode = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<= maxDegree; i++) {
        Node temp = allTerms;
        float fSum = 0;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.term.degree == i)
                fSum+=temp.term.coeff;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        if (fSum != 0)
            combinedNode = new Node(fSum, i, combinedNode);
    }
    return combinedNode;
}
```

Comment: Are you still working on this issue?  Curious if this code helped at all.  Cheers